# Quarkus REST API CORS configuration not working for consumer ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, docker, cors, quarkus

I have a ReactJS UI that is served by a static NGINX web server and a Quarkus REST API server. Both are dockerized services, and the ReactJS app is supposed to use the Quarkus REST API to consume data/make requests. In the depiction below we can see this simple setup for my localhost dev enironment (both services are exposed and mapped to different localhost ports):

[image: Dockerized services and request interaction]

In the deployed production environment, these will services will likely correspond to different hosts/URLs. The problem is, even in the localhost setup i expectedly have the issue of CORS errors when i try to make calls to the REST API service from the ReactJS app running in the clients browser, e.g. during login:

[image]

I have to admit, i dont fully understand CORS in terms of where exactly one has to make changes/configs to allow them - but i was told i need to set them in the server i make requests to (which in this case is the Quarkus REST API). So i added this setting in the Quarkus app `application.properties` to just generally allow all requests:

```
quarkus.http.cors=true
```

(as shown in https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#cors-filter)

In reality i should probably change this to be more precise, however i still receive the same CORS error in my browser when running the react web app. I understand that i could also configure a proxy in the NGINX server to tunnel requests to the other service container potentially, but i would like to solve this through CORS configuration. Where do i have to make which configurations for this to work? Did i make a mistake with the Quarkus config?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you **cannot only** set `quarkus.http.cors=true` for it to work and allow all requests, as per the Quarkus documentation. In my case i had to add more configurations, i.e.:

```
quarkus.http.cors=true
# This allows all origin hosts, should be specified if possible
quarkus.http.cors.origins=*
quarkus.http.cors.headers=accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
quarkus.http.cors.methods=GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
```